# Angular 10 Ivy With Webpack 4 Remove ng Debug Info

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-ivy

I have successfully build angular 10 ivy project with `@ngtools/webpack`.

Everything works fine but in prod build only issue is that  debug function are available, `ng.getContext()` `ng.getHostElement()`  `$0.__ngContext__` etc function are available on browser console.

I tried debugging the cli source code, from what i understood is that angular.json the flag enableOptimization determine the debug info.

How to pass that enableOptimization flag option from angular.json, some how to webpack ngtools.

Note: I'm not using cli.

**webpack.prod.js**

```
   plugins: [
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
          mainPath: resolve('./src/main.ts'),
          sourceMap: true,
          nameLazyFiles: false,
          tsConfigPath: resolve('./tsconfig.json'),
          // entryModule: resolve("app/app.module#AppModule" ),
          skipCodeGeneration: false,
          
        }),
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
```

Comment: Hi @vito - were you able to find a solution for this? I am also stuck at this point, it would be really helpful if you could provide me some pointers. Much appreciated!

Comment: @GovindSinghThakur ya i debugged ng cli and copied everything n its works now

Answer (score 0):

To remove angular debug context in prod, there are optimization keys that needs to added

> ```
> [https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/][1]
> ```

```
optimization: {
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        default: {
          chunks: 'async',
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: 10
        },
        common: {
          name: 'common',
          chunks: 'async',
          minChunks: 2,
          enforce: true,
          priority: 5
        },
        vendors: false,
        vendor: false
      }
    },
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        parallel: maxWorkers,
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false,
          },
          compress: {
            pure_getters: true,
            // PURE comments work best with 3 passes.
            // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2899#issuecomment-317425926.
            passes: true ? 3 : 1,
            global_defs: {
              ngJitMode: false,
              ngDevMode: false,
              ngI18nClosureMode: false
            }
          }
        },
        extractComments: false,
      }),
    ]
```

the **global_defs** terser options controls the debug helpers